# jq wildcard as object in getpath split

Tags: jq

Given a basic json

```json
{ 
    "notKnown": { 
        "alpha" : {
            "hello":"world"
        }
    } 
}
```

and then using `getpath` with a wildcard as an object does not seem to work

```
//Eg 1 - complete string generates correct result
myPath="notKnown.alpha.hello"
output=$(jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" 'getpath($str|split("."))' <<<$myJson) 
>> output="world"   

//Eg 2 - test the wildcard directly generates correct result
output=$(jq -r '.notKnown[].hello' <<<$myJson) 
>> output="world"

//Eg 3 - merge the wildcard into the formatting from Eg1 - generates null
myPath="notKnown[].hello"
output=$(jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" 'getpath($str|split("."))' <<<$myJson) 
>> output=null

//Eg 4 - merge the wildcard into the formatting from Eg1 - generates null
different example strings that generate null (assuming the first dot should not be used)
 myPath="[].alpha.hello"
 myPath=".[].alpha.hello" //leading dot expect fail
 myPath="[]alpha.hello"
 myPath=".[]alpha.hello"   //leading dot expect fail 

output=$(jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" 'getpath($str|split("."))' <<<$myJson)
>> output=null
```

Is there a way to have the format in `myPath` accept the wildcard as an object in the passed `$str` path?

Comment: What do you mean by wildcard? Getpath does not expects `[]` or `.`. So not sure what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: 0stone0 - Please undelete your deleted answer. I think it does answer the intended question, and e en if not, it does answer one reasonable reading thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getpath` doesn't take some query, but a list of keys.

You are effectively calling

```
getpath( [ "notKnown[]", "hello" ] )
```

This is equivalent to

```
.[ "notKnown[]" ][ "hello" ]
```

You could use

```
def _simple_query( $q ):
   if $q | length == 0 then
      .
   else
      $q[0] as $key |
      $q[1:] as $r |
      if $key == "*" then
         .[] | _simple_query( $r )
      else
         select( has( $key ) ) | .[ $key ] | _simple_query( $r )
      end
   end;

def simple_query( $q ):
   _simple_query( $q | split(".") );

simple_query( "*.alpha.hello" )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/P2fFNlcGI_) on jqplay

Comment: thanks for the code sample I will take a look at it and compare to the solution from @0stone0

Comment: with the username ikegami do you work on broadcast kit or just a coincidence?

Comment: @art vanderlay, No idea what that is

Comment: RE "*compare to the solution*", The other requires providing jq code, but is a lot simpler. This a more complicated (code-wise) solution allowing a simpler string to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to have the format in myPath accept the wildcard as an object in the passed $str path?

Don't think there is a way to let `getPath` deal with filters like
`.[].alpha.hello`

---

However, you can use the `myPath` variable as the *raw* filter itself to get the desired output:

```
$ myPath=".[].alpha.hello"
$ jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" "$myPath" json.json
world
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion, however our actual `myPath` includes `--arg` making it more complex, but pre expanding the args before passing it into jq should work as well using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Undeleting this due to @Peak's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72228178/jq-wildcard-as-object-in-getpath-split/72228933?noredirect=1#comment127615037_72228178)</sub>

---

[`getpath`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath(PATHS)) expects an array with just the keys, so we'll need the following to find the value:

```
getpath([ "notKnown", "alpha", "hello"  ])
```

---

So to get that using an arg, we can use your `split` command, but we'll need to remove the `.` and `[]` from the `myPath` var:

```
myPath="notKnown.alpha.hello"
jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" 'getpath($str|split("."))' json.json
```

---

Local shell demo:

```
$ jq . json.json
{
  "notKnown": {
    "alpha": {
      "hello": "world"
    }
  }
}
$
$ myPath="notKnown.alpha.hello"
$
$ jq -r --arg str "${myPath}" 'getpath($str|split("."))' json.json
world
$
```

Comment: You literally copied the OP's non-working code byte for byte. This does not answer the question.